# Stop jQuery conflict with slider

Tags: jquery

I am using the script below to show a time slider. The script works fine on all pages except for the homepage, so I am thinking it is conflicting with something. The site is running in Magento and the only difference I can think of is a module called flex-slider on the homepage.

I have added in jQuery no conflict but the time slider still doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#callback_selected').html("9 am");
  var select = jQuery( "#callback" );
  var slider = jQuery( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 12,
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    step: .5,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
        $time_int = ui.value;
        if (ui.value < 5) {
            $time_int = $time_int + 8;
            if ($time_int.toString().substr(-2) == '.5') $time_int = $time_int.toString().split('.')[0] + ":30";
            $time_selected = $time_int + " am";
        } else {
            $time_int = $time_int - 4;
            if ($time_int.toString().substr(-2) == '.5') $time_int = $time_int.toString().split('.')[0] + ":30";
            $time_selected = $time_int + " pm";
        }
      jQuery('#callback_selected').html($time_selected);
      jQuery("#time").val($time_selected);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: then check the exact error with firefbug or in Chrome.

Comment: check for duplicate references to jquery libs.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.noConflict();` Is supposse to use when you work with (and load) other libraries at the same time or in the same page.

If you use `noConflict` then you **must** use the same format in your function.

Note the difference beteewn dolar sign and jQuery word:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
jQuery("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

So... for your code, I would change all `$` to `jQuery` word, this must be enought to work with no problem. (and then, noConflict can be removed)
Of course, the jQuery function must be called (or at least is recommended) on document ready.

---

Another option if you want to keep your `$` alias, is replace all `jQuery` with `$` sign but replace the `noConflict call` like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    // code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**note the dollar in `(function($){...`**

In this case, `$` is an alias to `jQuery`, but remember to use always `$` inside that function.

---

> *Finnally, and my expirence and best practice in real world, is to use **allways** `jQuery` word... then there's no need to fight with no conflict
>   in most of the cases. (as they normally use `$` sign)*

---

More examples and descriptions in: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Good luck!